# Use a timer when a key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, timer, action

The past week of searching has not brought up any working help for trying to figure out how to do this. When a user presses the backspace, it saves the game. I set it up that it shows a little box at the top that says "Saving.." and I want that to stay up there for about 2 seconds. I can get it to show up while the button is being pressed with this code:

```
if (key.save) {
    font = new Font(null, 0, 16);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(getWidth() / 2 - 40, -1, 80, 35);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(getWidth() / 2 - 40, -1, 80, 35);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Saving..", getWidth() / 2 - 30, 22);
}
```

But this code won't work, it won't even display the box at the top:

```
if (key.save) {
    ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Font font = new Font(null, 0, 16);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(getWidth() / 2 - 40, -1, 80, 35);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(getWidth() / 2 - 40, -1, 80, 35);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("Saving..", getWidth() / 2 - 30, 22);
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(0, action);
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Painting should be done in a centralized location.  This means that each time the screen is refreshed, it is rebuilt to represent the current state of the UI, this would include messages.  This way you could use another timer to change the state of the UI and have the message removed the next time the screen is repainted.  I *HOPE* you're using double buffering and not `getGraphics`...

Comment: Yes I'm double-buffering. I really don't understand how I would "use another timer to change the state of the UI and have the message removed the next time the screen is repainted."

Comment: The Graphics object, g, should not be a field of the class, and you're using it as such suggests that your code is messed up. Have you gone through the Swing Graphics tutorials as they would help you a lot. By "change the state of the UI", he means that you would change class fields, call `repaint()` and have the `paintComponent(...)` method use those fields to change the displayed graphics.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. 3) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details on use.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This comment doesn't fit here. There is no `Thread.sleep`, no concurrency issues which you can deduce from the small code snippet shown here.

Comment: This is slightly off topic, but can either @MadProgrammer or Shzylo recommend any good places to read about double buffering, esp. as it applies in Java? I've not heard much about it before and would like to read a bit about it.

Comment: @Howard  *"no concurrency issues which you can deduce from the small code snippet shown here."*  And what exactly can you determine from the code that ***isn't*** there?  That comment was just offered as 'just in case' the OP is doing something in the missing code that ..7 times out of 10, is caused by attempting to do something on on the EDT that should be done off the EDT.  Until we see an SSCCE, we cannot know for sure either away, but since I had extra characters left at the end of the comment, thought I'd throw that in for good measure.

Comment: @Shzylo I'd start with some kind `Drawable` concept.  An object, which can be placed on a `List` and your main paint loop can use to "draw" content on the screen.  This interface would simple have a `draw(Graphics)` method (for example).  When called, it would paint it's required content to the screen.  You would then add a `MessageDrawable` to this `List` and start another `Timer` that is capable of removing it

Comment: @Kon I start by having a look at [Passive vs. Active Rendering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html) and [Java Games: Active Rendering](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-active-rendering-r2418) for some ideas

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good idea with the `Drawable` thing - might be used for other cases also.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is an example of the basic concept of using a list of renderable artifacts which can be updated over time.

The basic idea is there is a central paint loop that is responsible for updating the current state of the UI based on what you want to render.  This means that any changes to the UI must go through this central loop.

This example just uses Swing, but the concept should be easy to translate.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class QuickPaint01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuickPaint01();
    }

    public QuickPaint01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Environment {

        private List<Drawable> drawables;

        public TestPane() {
            drawables = new ArrayList<>(25);
            Timer update = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Drawable[] draws = drawables.toArray(new Drawable[drawables.size()]);
                    for (Drawable drawable : draws) {
                        if (drawable instanceof Moveable) {
                            ((Moveable)drawable).update(TestPane.this);
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            update.setCoalesce(true);
            update.setRepeats(true);
            update.start();
            drawables.add(new Ball());
        }

        @Override
        public void add(Drawable drawable) {
            drawables.add(drawable);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(Drawable drawable) {
            drawables.remove(drawable);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
                drawable.draw(this, g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public interface Environment {

        public Dimension getSize();
        public void add(Drawable drawable);
        public void remove(Drawable drawable);

    }

    public interface Drawable {

        public void draw(Environment env, Graphics2D g);

    }

    public interface Moveable extends Drawable {

        public void update(Environment env);

    }

    public class Ball implements Moveable {

        private int radius = 20;

        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 0;

        private int xDelta = 4;

        private Shape shape;

        public Ball() {
            shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, radius, radius);
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Environment env) {
            x += xDelta;
            if (x + radius > env.getSize().width) {

                x = env.getSize().width - radius;
                xDelta *= -1;

                env.add(new Message(env, "<< Bounce", 1));

            } else if (x < 0) {

                x = 0;
                xDelta *= -1;

                env.add(new Message(env, "Bounce >> ", 1));

            }
            y = (env.getSize().height - radius) / 2;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Environment env, Graphics2D g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.translate(x, y);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class Message implements Drawable {

        private Environment environment;
        private String message;
        private int delay;

        public Message(Environment environment, String message, int delay) {
            this.environment = environment;
            this.message = message;
            this.delay = delay;

            Timer timer = new Timer(delay * 1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Message.this.environment.remove(Message.this);
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Environment env, Graphics2D g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            g2d.drawString(message, env.getSize().width - fm.stringWidth(message), 0 + fm.getAscent());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Written in pseudo code you can build a solution using several parts:

- Introduce a field `saveMessageIsVisible` which is set to `false`
- Inside the key handling method

  - clone the game state
  - start a new thread and save the state
  - at the end of this thread, set `saveMessageIsVisible` to true (and optionally perform invalidate screen)
  - also start a timer with 2 seconds duration after which you set the field to false again.
- Inside the paint routine check for the field and draw your save box.

Answer (score 0):

for perform a task for a given period of time, you could do the following:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
try {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         // task
       }
    };

    Future<?> f = service.submit(r);

    f.get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);     // attempt the task for two minutes
} catch (Exception e) {
     //Handele Exception
} finally {
     service.shutdown();
}
```