# Jr Java-er Wants to Pass Params to Paint

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, paint

I'm currently able to draw rectangles, elipses, and lines in Java by means of adding a component that extends JComponent in which I modify a paintComponent method:

```
public class myComponent extends JComponent
{
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
    /* do simple draw stuff */
   }
}
```

I also know how to have my class extend either JApplet or JPanel and then draw in a paint method:

```
public class myClass extends JPanel
{
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
    /* do simple draw stuff */
   }
}
```

But, both of these methods suffer from not allowing me to pass them parameters.  In the case of a multiframe animated sprite, I could conceivably have some external variable that it reads to determine the frame number and then internally draws only the appropriate "sprite" contents based on that frame number, but I'd prefer to be able to pass the frame number to it directly.  Unfortunately, not only do I not know where this is called from, I don't know where to the the Graphics g that it requires as input.

There may be a better way to accomplish what I want, to directly communicate with the draw routine to tell it to draw only what I want, whenever I desire, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

If such a method is possible, how would that be done?
If it is better to use the existing paint or paintComponent methods, how can I best pass additional information to them?

---

Apparently I wasn't clear in what I asked.  I wish to have a component or other entity that has its own paintComponent or paint method, inside of which, based on either a frameNumber parameter that is passed to it, or apparently-more-likely, a class property such as frameNumber that it can access, the method determines which frame of a sprite to draw.

Importantly, though, I wish to be able to re-call paint or paintComponent to redraw the sprite when the frame number changes.  My big confusion comes in not knowing how to re-call the method, which, to the best of my understanding, only is called when the frame is resized or otherwise redrawn.

### So, how can I redraw my component/object/entity, frame-by-frame?

Comment: ok, that's weird.  That last line looks like I'm shouting.  Not quite sure what happened there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't override `paint`, use `paintComponent`.

Secondly, you need to define some kind of model which records the state of all the graphical objects.  When `paintComponent` is called, you then need to render that state.  Instead of trying to pass parameters to the paint methods, you should have a method which allows the paint methods to access the model (ie `getModel`) which is passed to the component at some earlier time.

Then the update engine would update the model and the component would paint that model

For an example ... [Use a timer when a key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562252/use-a-timer-when-a-key-is-pressed/17562792#17562792)

Comment: So, how would you re-invoke the paintComponent method?

Comment: Under Swing, I'd simply call `repaint` either on the component that needs to be updated or the parent container - as is shown in the linked example

Comment: Thank you.  That repaint() is what this jr. java-er didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

> I could conceivably have some external variable that it reads to determine the frame number and then internally draws only the appropriate "sprite" contents based on that frame number

Your class would need to have some internal state, i.e. instance variables.

You can then inspect those within the `paint` method.

Answer (score 1):

Think "member variables":

```
public class MyClass extends JPanel {

   private final int frameNumber;

   public MyClass() { 
       this(0);
   }

   public MyClass(int f) { 
       this.frameNumber = f; 
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
       if (this.frameNumber == x) {
        /* do simple draw stuff */
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: ok, so this is the method of having an external variable that the paint routine reads.  But, how do I re-invoke paint after I've changed the frameNumber variable?  I know that paint is called when the window is resized or minimized/maximized, but would it be re-executed automagically if the number changed?

Comment: No, it would not.  And the code I wrote will not allow you to change the number.